# 11month old baby has lost interest in eating solids

Tags: infant, eating, feeding

My 11 month old daughter has suddenly lost interest in eating her solids. She has never really been interested in food however we were in a good routine and she was eating the foods I was giving her, mainly tomato based foods i.e pasta, beef casserole. She would also eat some toast at breakfast time and puree fruit a snack time.

Over the past week or so she has stoped opening her mouth to eat or will only open it slightly and wont take anything of the spoon. After doing this a few times she will start pushing the spoon away. With her toast in the morning she will just break it up and throw it on the floor.

She has been a little unwell and my husband believes that this has caused her to loose her appetite, however I can't help but feel that it's more then that and not sure what is the best way to get her back on track with her eating. She is bottle feed which she is taking 3 - 4 bottles a day.

Any advise or assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some of the responses to these questions might help you: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4292 http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/1846